# How do I add multiple links in each table row form table?

Tags: theming, forms

I am new to drupal 8. I have created a form listing in admin.Now i want to add three or more links for operation(Edit/Delete/Suspend) in single TD columns. Can anyone let me know how to do this? I tried by concatenation two links but did not work. I am creating links as below.

```
$query = \Drupal::database()->select('vacations', 'v');
    $query->fields('v');
    $table_sort = $query->extend('Drupal\Core\Database\Query\TableSortExtender')->orderByHeader($header);
    $pager = $table_sort->extend('Drupal\Core\Database\Query\PagerSelectExtender')->limit(10);
    //$results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
    $results = $pager->execute();
    // Initialize an empty array
    $output = array();
// Next, loop through the $results array
    foreach ($results as $key => $result) {
      $approve_link = Link::fromTextAndUrl(t('Approve'), Url::fromRoute('vacation_forms.operations', ['ID' => $result->id, 'action' => 'approve']))->toString();
      $reject_link = Link::fromTextAndUrl(t('Reject'), Url::fromRoute('vacation_forms.operations', ['ID' => $result->id, 'action' => 'reject']))->toString();
      $newLink = $approve_link; // this works
      //$newLink = $approve_link . "|" . $reject_link; //this does not work it shows plain html in table columns
      $output[$result->id] = [
        //'id' => $result->id,
        'employee_name' => $result->employee_name,
        'employee_email' => $result->employee_email,
        'vacation_start_date' => $result->vacation_start_date,
        'vacation_end_date' => $result->vacation_end_date,
        'leave_days' => $result->leave_days,
        'status' => $result->status,
        'operations' => $newLink,
      ];
    }
    $form['table'] = [
      '#type' => 'tableselect',
      '#header' => $header,
      '#options' => $output,
      '#empty' => t('No users found'),
    ];
```

I am using Drupal 8.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! So far you are just stating facts which aren't totally clear. You need to show all the code you are using; that is only a minimal part. We cannot say what you are doing wrong without seeing the code. Then, we aren't a _write the code for me_ service, so a request like _this is all my code; fill the holes with the missing code_ is not acceptable.

Comment: I only want to show to links "Approve | Reject". Approve and reject both will be href links. Below is the full function for your reference.

Comment: The above $output array is in for each loop after querying the DB. Two links one for approve and second for reject is required. Every admin listing has these links. But I am not able to show them in a single column. Remember I am using Drupal 8.

Comment: I have updated the question and put my full code.Please check reply.

Answer (score 1):

After a long research i was able to acheive this as follows:

```
$approve_link = Link::fromTextAndUrl(t('Approve'), Url::fromRoute('vacation_forms.operations', ['ID' => $result->id, 'action' => 'approve']))->toString();
$reject_link = Link::fromTextAndUrl(t('Reject'), Url::fromRoute('vacation_forms.operations', ['ID' => $result->id, 'action' => 'reject']))->toString();
$mainLink = t('@linkApprove | @linkReject', array('@linkApprove' => $approve_link, '@linkReject' => $reject_link));
```

and then use $mainLink in foreach loop.
Thanks for all your help.